# How do I create a hierarchy of UNIX groups as below?

Tags: linux, permissions, ldap, acl

I need to create a hierarchy of UNIX groups. Something like below:

```
A
|\
| \
B  c
|\
D e
|\
f g
```

...where A, B and D are UNIX groups and c,e,f and g are UNIX accounts that are members of those specific groups. I have googled a lot but it seems that this is not possible.

**Currently, we have the following:**

1. Group A has members c.
2. Group B has members e.
3. Group D has members f,g.

---

**UPDATE:**

@John's post made me realize that I needed to re-frame my requirements to remove the ambiguity.

**What I require is:**

1. Limit access to a directory only to members of group B (so B is
   group owner of that folder). As group D is a sub-group of B, members of D would be members of group B and have access to that directory as well.
2. But members of Group B needs to have the same rights as members of group A. (So if group A is a directory group owner then automatically group B is the directory group-owner).

   By the way, this is a real-world problem where I have full control over group B and its members; and limited or no control over other groups and their members. So I cannot create new groups and give membership to members from group A or D.

Comment: You don't with normal groups. You may could use something else like LDAP

Comment: Thanks @UlrichDangel. Okay, we are using LDAP groups. Except B is a local group. So if I request the LDAP admins to create group B as a LDAP group then how should I go about requesting for this hierarchy..? Could you kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: TBH i don't think it will work with local groups. And I also don't know enough of LDAP but afaik, at least for some products, it should be possible to have virtual groups, e.g. groups consisting of other groups. Please be aware that I don't know if this is the proper term.

Comment: @UlrichDangel - Will get back to you if I come across anything like that. Right now I am looking into ACLs..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With normal unix permissions, you can't do this.

With ACLs you can (or should be able to).

You need to be using a filesystem that supports ACLs. Most modern linux filesystems do.

The basic command is setfacl

In your example, if group B owns directory /B you would add access rights for group D as follows:

```
setfacl -m group:B:rwx,group:D:rwx /B
```

This is only the most basic example but might get the idea across. This does require careful and explicit setting of access control, but can do much more than basic unix permissions. It isn't nearly as capable as, as full AD group policy and the like, though.

[Here's some documentation of ACLs in general](http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/chapter/fs_acl-en.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @SuperMagic for your inputs! I will need a while to get familiar with ACLs and decide whether it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: The below points seem to satisfy my requirements, though different then what I had originally planned.. But do you see any issue with this while using ACLs? .. as I am still getting acquainted with them.

1. Each user in group B and D have membership to group A.
2. Directory owned by group B is made accessible only to group B and its members. 
3. Using ACLs I will allow group D members to access the above directory. (Your example shows this..)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrich says, you can't do this with traditional groups. Your file permissions are limited to one owner, one group, and "everyone else". You may be able to accomplish your access requirements by having users in multiple groups, but even then limits 1 and 3 are mutually exclusive, presenting a problem. The solution you need is based in either LDAP or filesystem ACLs, I'm not sure which without knowing a lot more about the problem.

Comment: Thanks John. Sorry, I didn't understand the part "...but even then limits 1 and 3 are mutually exclusive...". Also if there is any more specific information I could provide you with, please do let me know.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Limit 1 instructs you to limit access to a certain directory to members of group B. Limit 1 then instructs you to ensure all members of group D have the same access to the previously mentioned directory, violating limit 1.

Comment: Note that LDAP is just a directory, which can hand out data for an account or group in this case, nothing more. It won't let you go past  the (smallish) number of groups an account can belong to (that is fixed by the kernel), and doesn't help in the resultimg mess of "Hum, I need to share this with A, but leave out B and D, so the right group is..."

Comment: @John - The limits I had mentioned were a bit ambiguous, hence my confusion when who pointed out that #1and #3 were mutually exclusive. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @vonbrand - Okay, so if I have understand that correctly then my ONLY option would be to go in for ACLs correct?

Comment: Yes, ACLs the only practical way.